React.js exporting functions to main App.js folder not working
Created a function.js folder with a simple hello world statement. When trying to export this function to the App.js folder it doesnt work
tried rewriting the code and starting a new program. Expecting Hello World to be generated on the web page
App.js
(https://i.sstatic.net/Ssr65.png)
function.js
(https://i.sstatic.net/QeiNV.png)

Any output in the browser console?

you should make the component name to be title cased, start with capital letter, function Test(){....} ... this way react knows its a component and not html tag to call it and render accordingly

Few things to remember,

Start the component name in capital letter to differ from native HTML elements so react treats them as components and call it to render the JSX returned from it or import it as a capital letter when it is default exported (thanks to Konrad ).
you could name the files with .jsx or .tsx if you are using typescript ..
please check the console for helpful errors, warnings that has the solution in itself recommending like the above case shows something as:


Adding a simple e.g. on what you are trying to achieve, with both the working and not working components ( you could remove the lowercased component which was added for demo purpose)
function Test() ✅ react is happy to treat it as a component and calls it to render the jsx returned
funtion test() ❌ react is unhappy as it thinks as a native html which shouldn't be called by it
Hope it helps  .. happy coding !!

Renaming the function will do nothing here, because it's the import which is faulty

import is faulty, sorry I could see it as okay

Should be import Test from './function'. When you export default, the name of the function is ignored and can e renamed to anything when importing

oh yeah, this too .... default is crime
Thanks for that, added the point
